# How to parse a list in Django urlparser?

Tags: python, regex, django

On Stack Overflow, you can view a list of questions with multiple tags at a URL such as `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django+python`.

I'd like to do something similar in a project I am working on, where one of the url parameters would be a list of tags, but I'm not sure how to write a regex urlparser that can parse it out. I'm fond of SO's way of using the `+` sign, but it's not a dealbreaker. I also imagine that the urlparser may have to take the whole string (foo+bar+baz) as a single variable to give to the view, which is also fine as I can just split it in the view itself- that is, I'm not expecting the URL parser to give the view an already split list, but if it can, even better!

Right now all I have is:

```
url(r'^documents/tag/(?P<tag>\w+)/$', ListDocuments.as_view(), name="list_documents"),
```

Which just pulls out one single tag since `\w+` just gets me those `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, but not `+`. I tried something like:

```
url(r'^documents/tag/(?P<tag>[\w+\+*])/$', ListDocuments.as_view(), name="list_documents"),
```

But this no longer matched `documents/tag/foo` nor `documents/tag/foo+bar`.

Please assist, I'm not so great with regex, thanks!

Comment: I'm not so great with regex either, but can't we use   `str.split('\')[-1].split('+')` to get the tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do this automatically. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#notes-on-capturing-text-in-urls): "Each captured argument is sent to the view as a plain Python string, regardless of what sort of match the regular expression makes." Splitting it in the view is the way to go.

The second regex in your answer is OK, but it does allow some things you might not want (e.g. `'django+++python+'`). A stricter version might be something like: `(?P<tag>\w+(?:\+\w+)*)`. Then you can just do a simple `tag.split('+')` in the view without worrying about any edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

This works for now:

```
url(r'^documents/tag/(?P<tag>[A-Za-z0-9_\+]+)/$', ListDocuments.as_view(), name="list_documents"),
```

But I'd like to be able to get that `w` back in there instead of the full list of characters like that.

[Edit]

Here we go:

```
url(r'^documents/tag/(?P<tag>[\w\+]+)/$', ListDocuments.as_view(), name="list_documents"),
```

I will still select a better answer if there is a way for the Django urlparser to give the view an actual list instead of just one big long string, but if that's not possible, this solution does work.